# Why is sscanf not reading the first argument in the format string?

Tags: c, string, string-formatting, scanf

In the following program, everything but the first value (the month) in the format string is being read into the SYSTEMTIME structure.  Can anyone help me figure this one out?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    char buf[50];
    strcpy(buf, "6/23/2015 12:00:00");
    sscanf(buf, "%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d", &st.wMonth, &st.wDay, &st.wYear, &st.wHour, &st.wMinute, &st.wSecond);
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
2015 0 23 12 0 0
```

It should be:

```
2015 6 23 12 0 0
```

Comment: Try `%hu` instead of `%d`.

Comment: MinGW gives several warnings like :`warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 3 has type 'WORD *' [-Wformat=]`

Comment: @Cool Guy, that worked;if you post an answer with details about *why* that works I'll accept it to give you credit. :)

Comment: @MichaelBurr I was using MSVC, which doesn't seem to issue warnings for type mismatches in format strings

Comment: @GovindParmar: no, unfortunately, MSVC doesn't.have the capability of warning for mismatched `printf`/`scanf` format specifiers. This is one example that shows how It can be beneficial to compile and run code using different compilers.  That might be difficult for larger projects, but it's usually possible with smaller snippets used to demonstrate problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier. `%d` is used for `int`s. Is `st.*` an `int`? No.

As per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `SYSTEMTIME` structure is defined as

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
  WORD wYear;
  WORD wMonth;
  WORD wDayOfWeek;
  WORD wDay;
  WORD wHour;
  WORD wMinute;
  WORD wSecond;
  WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME;
```

Now, What's `WORD`?

Quoting from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> **WORD**
>
> A 16-bit unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 65535 decimal.
>
> This type is declared in `WinDef.h` as follows:
>
> ```
> typedef unsigned short WORD;
> ```

So, `WORD`(`st.*`) is an `unsigned short`. The correct format specifier for an `unsigned short` is `%hu`. Using the wrong format specifier leads to [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as per the standard (n1570):

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 13. If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. <sup>287)</sup>